# Tomorrow evening OR evening tomorrow OR

Tags: word-order

Which is correct and how to use all of it?

> 1) I will come tomorrow in the evening
>
> 2) I will come in the tomorrow's evening
>
> 3) I will come in the evening tomorrow
>
> 4) I will come tomorrow evening
>
> 5) I will come the tomorrow evening
>
> 6) I will come in the tomorrow evening

Or what are there other variants....?

Answer (score 2):

1,3,4 are the only ones that sound grammatical. Generally you do not say “the tomorrow”- “tomorrow” is specific enough that you don’t need to further qualify it with “the”. 4 sounds the most natural.

Comment: Can't "tomorrow" be like an adjective?
"I will come in the winter evening", I will come in the Monday evening, I will come in tomorrow evening, no?

But "I will come tomorrow evening" sounds so awkward for me...
I see "tomorrow" like an adjective which requires a preposition and an article before itself. Like, we don't say "I will come hot evening". But if it's "tomorrow" then anyway - in the tomorrow evening. But even if we don't use "the", the preposition should be anyway - tomorrow in the evening, or "in tomorrow evening" or something cause, it's so weird...

Comment: “In tomorrow evening” is not grammatical, though “tomorrow, in the evening” is. “In” only works with certain time expressions- like general times of day- “in the morning”, “in the daytime”, “in the afternoon”, “in the evening”. For whatever reason, “at night” is the usual expression rather than “in the night”- though the latter is not wrong. When you are more specific with the time- “tomorrow evening”, “Monday afternoon”, “February 15th”, etc- you would not use “in” or “the”. “On” would be used for the latter 2 expressions. Not sure if there’s a reason for this or if it’s just idiomatic.

Comment: You could say “the Monday after next” (another situation where “the” is acceptable). “During” is often used for a period of time that lasts for a while- e.g. “during the last week of February” or “during the day” (meaning “in the daytime/morning hours”) or “during the hour from 2-3 PM” or “during the twenty-first century”. But for time expressions like “yesterday”, “today”, or “tomorrow” you do not use any preposition or article. Maybe you can think of the preposition being built in - “tomorrow” is equivalent to “during/on the day that comes after today”.

Comment: 1) But if we say time: tomorrow and evening, whould they go in the order of increasement like firstly "in the evening" and then "tomorrow" because "tomorrow" is more global
2) We say "on Monday afternon", you mean? It's correct, right? If it has a comma - then I understand: "on Monday, afternoon" but then there should be "in the" between "," and "afternoon". 
3) The Monday after next? What does it mean? Like, the second Monday?
4) But wouldn't "in the morning hours" be like "after the morning hours are over" instead of "during the morning hours"?

Comment: My God, if native speakers see "tomorrow" like "during the day which goes after this one" then it turns my brain over...

Comment: 1- “tomorrow evening”, “tomorrow in the evening”, “in the evening tomorrow” are all acceptable but the first is most concise and most natural to say. 2- “on Monday afternoon” and “on Monday in the afternoon” are both fine but again the 1st is preferred 3- yes, “Mon after next” is a week after the soonest Mon from now 4- no- why do you think “in the morning hours” means “after the morning hours are over”? “In” is equivalent to “during” here.

Comment: Did not mean to confuse you - I meant that you can think of “tomorrow” as having “on” or “during” built into it- so you don’t use a preposition with it. You would say “I have an appointment on February 17th” but you would say “I have an appointment tomorrow”- no “in”, “on”, “during” needed- also no “the” needed

Comment: Okay, if we can take "tomorrow" for "during tomorrow" then it will be this:
"I will come "during tomorrow evening". Doesn't it require an article?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko again - no. No article or preposition is used with "tomorrow" or "tomorrow [morning/afternoon/evening/night]". The way you say it is just "I will come tomorrow evening".